# Postgresql: cannot set default privileges on tables

Tags: postgresql, docker

On Postgres 9.6 on Docker I run this in my entrypoint:

```
    psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 --username "$POSTGRES_USER" <<-EOSQL
        BEGIN;
            CREATE ROLE $rouser LOGIN PASSWORD '$POSTGRES_READONLY_PASSWORD';
            GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE $database TO $rouser;
            GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO $rouser;
            GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO $rouser;

            ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO $rouser;

            ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO $rouser;
            alter default privileges for role $POSTGRES_USER grant select on tables to $rouser;
            alter default privileges for role $POSTGRES_USER in schema public grant select on tables to $rouser;

            alter default privileges grant select on sequences to $rouser;
            alter default privileges in schema public grant select on sequences to $rouser;
            alter default privileges for role $POSTGRES_USER grant select on sequences to $rouser;
            alter default privileges for role $POSTGRES_USER in schema public grant select on sequences to $rouser;
        COMMIT;
EOSQL
```

Basically I just want $rouser to have select privileges on all tables created at any time.

This code above works only if the tables are already created, but not for future tables, basically the defaults are not working.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The code only works for tables created by the `$POSTGRES_USER` role, not for any table.

Comment: $POSTGRES_USER is the user creating the new tables.

Comment: This works for me, provided the database I am connected to when executing it is the same as `$database`.

Comment: In my code above I show various attempts to reproduce solutions from other answers, unfortunately none working.